# Moving data from staging table to production table uses up to 200GB of Log space

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction-log

I have multiple staging tables containing data that needs to be moved to production tables. The process of moving this data is done within a transaction to make it possible to rollback everything in case the process fails.
The most log consuming operations are:

- Deleting old data from production tables
- Inserting new data into production tables

The query used to delete the old data is:

```
DELETE FROM PROD_TABLE WHERE CONDITION
```

A simple truncate is not possible since not all the data can be deleted.

The data to be deleted and the data to be moved is about 200 Million records.

Is there anyway to improve the process to reduce the log consomption.

Comment: Would it be possible to segment the data?

Comment: What do you mean by segmenting data and how? The important thing is that whole process can be rolled back

Comment: By date for example.

Comment: data can be segmented but I don't see how that would help. Because after copiying N segments if one segment fails the already moved segments needs to be rolled back. meaning everything needs to be within the same transaction.

Comment: @ayou392, with segmented processing, you would use separate transactions by date and, in the case of failure, undo previously committed transactions with reversing inserts/deletes. The implication is data will be inconsistent until the entire ETL process completes. You mentioned 200M rows are deleted and inserted. How many are left untouched? Can the ETL process have exclusive access to the table for the duration of the process?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes exclusive access is possible, though restoring the database to a valid state using reverse insert/delete doesn't sound like the right way to rollback changes since even that reverse process might fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to look at partition switching - the staging table could be switched in to the production table, and the production table switched out to a history table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-switching-partitions-between-tables gives an example of a switch out. There are quite a few blogs about the technique, look up a few and see if they match what you are trying to do.

A system I used to work on had a monthly data load. The data was staged to a table, which was then switched in to the live table. The live table had a partition per month. It was very quick as I think it's a metadata operation. HTH